# Visual Studio 2015, Resharper freezing on debug UnitTests

Tags: c#, debugging, resharper, visual-studio-2015

I'm using the community-edition of Visual Studio 2015 (Windows 10) and have my resharper-extension (incl. Debugging Option) enabled.

when I start debugging my c#-Test-classes Visual Studio freezes and i have to minimize and maximize VS to get a refreshed Screen (for every Debugging-step).

When I disable Resharper's debugging-Option and use the build-in VS-debugging everything works fine.

I want to use Resharper because its much more comfortable.

Has anyone any idea if this is just an Option i have to set?

EDIT: VS is only freezing when I debug Unit-Tests.

Comment: What version are you using? 9.1.2 has known issues with VS2015 RTM. Try 9.1.3.

Comment: I'm using Version 9.1.3 already

Comment: I would suggest disabling ReSharper to see if the errors continue (tricky when you're using ReSharper's test runner, admittedly). If so, try updating to 9.2, the second RC has just been released)

Comment: when i disable resharper and use the pool build-in-test-functionality everything works fine...its definetly resharper which is causing this error. I will try to update to 9.2

Comment: Did the upgrade solve the problem? I have the same issue.

Comment: Resharper is absolutely killing my productivity in VS2015.  Opening WinForm designer causes hang, Debug causes hang, Clean causes hang.  None of these are present if I disable Resharper (9.2).

Comment: unfortunately the debugging-problems are still there. Even with resharper 9.2...

Comment: Same problem here. Just upgraded to R# 10, but it kills the IDE. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an Update of Microsoft Visual Studio which fixed the Problems for me.

this are my Version-Numbers where the Problem doesn't occur anymore.

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 
Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1

JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2015.2

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, this is a show stopper bug in 10.0 RTM. It's being fixed and will be in a 10.0.1 hot fix released ASAP, either this week or next. See [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-450426) for tracking, voting and more details.

Answer (score -1):

I'm developing a new project with unit test and I have the same problem, when I start debugging my unit test Visual Studio freezes I have to minimize and maximize VS to get a refreshed Screen.

When I disable Resharper's debugging-Option everything works fine.